# Flex Mobile set the Status Bar Color on iPhone / iPad

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, mobile, statusbar

I've been meaning to set the Status Bar Style of the iPhone (the upper bar with network, time and battery status) to have the dark color or transparent.

I've searched online and have noticed what needs to be set

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]`

`setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];`

I know that these properties and value should be added to the `appname-app.xml` of my Flex Mobile project in the iPhone tag:
`<iPhone>
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[`

I'm not sure though what is the key / values to set to achieve a dark colored or semi transparent status bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

In your appname-xml.xml file of your Flex Project, scroll to the `<iPhone>` tag and should have the following key / value:

```
<iPhone>
<InfoAdditions>
         <![CDATA[
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
      ]]>
</InfoAdditions>    
</iPhone>
```